# how to install approxeng on windows 10

Tags: python, pip

I tried writing the command `pip install approxeng.input` on command prompt and it raised an error that said

```
The 'linux/input.h' and 'linux/input-event-codes.h' include files
are missing. You will have to install the kernel header files in
order to continue:

    yum install kernel-headers-$(uname -r)
    apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
    emerge sys-kernel/linux-headers
    pacman -S kernel-headers
```

can anybody help me understand what I'm supposed to do?

Comment: https://github.com/ApproxEng/approxeng.input/#readme: "*You may need to install some prerequisites first, and this will **only work on Linux** based operating systems. See the full docs for more details.*" @forever What OS do you use? Windows?

Comment: yes, I am on windows 10.

Comment: Perhaps this could work if you use windows subsystem for linux (WSL) ? That will give you a linux environment in windows 10.

Comment: do you know how to download WSL?

Comment: i just downloaded WSL and it worked.